# How to change value of input with same name using Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, automation, automated-tests, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

So there is a form in which input are like this

```
<input class="input _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-32" focusableelement="" aria-invalid="false" aria-labelledby="930C5093-F4DD-4A01-BD2E-96F2873C8559--0" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" type="money64">
```

So there are two inputs like the above. I want to change value of first input to X and second input to Y.

```
await page.$eval('input[type=money64]', el => el.value = 'X');
await page.$eval('input[type=money64]', el => el.value = 'Y');
```

The above code changes the value of the same input first to X then to Y and the second input remains the same. So how can I set the value of second input type = money64 using puppeteer.

Comment: You can use :nth-child

Comment: thanks @AmanGupta, can u please help me with the code or write the code that I can use. I have just started node and puppeteer

Comment: Can you provide the HTML structure? Does the parent of these inputs have any other child?

Comment: <input class="input _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-32" focusableelement="" aria-invalid="false" aria-labelledby="D69A3119-9FF1-4EBA-83AA-EF2B7D0D9579--0" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" type="money64">

Comment: <input class="input _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-32" focusableelement="" aria-invalid="false" aria-labelledby="D69A3119-9FF1-4EBA-83AA-EF2B7D0D9579--0" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" type="money64">

Comment: @AmanGupta both inputs are repeated except for type everything gets changed since it is randomly generated on google's Admanager UI

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="abc">
    <input class="custom1" type="text" >
    <input class="custom2" type="text">
</div>


 let firstInput = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#abc input:nth-child(1)'));
// change content for the firstInput
// repeat the same for the second child
```

Try this.

You can also try:

```
await page.$eval('#abc input:nth-child(1)', el => el.value = 'X');
await page.$eval('#abc input:nth-child(2)', el => el.value = 'Y');
```

Check this.

Comment: Can you post your code? what have you done and what error are you getting

Comment: I am not getting error it's just that the second input doesn't gets updated

Comment: @vyom wont be able to help without knowing what you have tried. Please add your code.

Comment: just need your last help, if this is the xpath from chrome how can i change value of input    /html/body/div[1]/root/div/div/div/div/child-container-dart/div/exchange/unified-pricing/pricing-rule-list/pricing-rule-detail/form/drx-list-slidealog/drx-slidealog/focus-trap/div[2]/material-drawer/div/div[2]/drx-form-section[3]/div/div[2]/subrule-list-editor/div[2]/subrule-editor/subrule-cpm-thresholds-editor/div[2]/cpm-threshold-editor/material-input/div[1]/div[1]/label/input

Comment: I have updated my answer. If it doesnt work, you need to update your question with proper code and sample HTML. else no one will be able to help you.